# NVCC separate compilation with PTX output

Tags: gcc, cuda, nvcc, ptxas

Just to see what kind of code CUDA is generating I like to compile to ptx in addition to an object file. Since some of my loop unrolling can take quite a while I'd like to be able to compile **`*.cu`→`*.ptx`→`*.o`** instead of wasting time with both **`*.cu`→`*.ptx`** and **`*.cu`→`*.o`**, which I'm currently doing.

Simply adding `-ptx` to the `nvcc *.cu` line gives the desired ptx output.

Using `ptxas -c` to compile `*.ptx` to `*.o` works, but causes an error in my executable linking: `Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 190)`.

Attempting to compile the `*.ptx` with `nvcc` fails *silently*, outputting nothing.

[this image is quite helpful:
[image]](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda)

Is there some option I need to pass to `ptxas`? How should I properly compile via ptx with separate compilation? Alternatively, can I just tell `nvcc` to keep the ptx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Alternatively, can I just tell nvcc to keep the ptx?

Yes, you can tell nvcc to [keep all intermediate files](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-guiding-compiler-driver), one of which will be the `.ptx` file.

```
nvcc -keep ...
```

Keeping all the intermediate files is a bit messy, but I'm sure you can come up with a script to tidy things up, and only save the files you want.